# Unknown QEvent type

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a Qt application written in Python (with PyQt4) and, in the process of debugging a bug, I installed an event filter on my widget:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, ev):
    print "Event:", ev, " | type:", ev.type()
```

One of the (many) lines of output was the following:

```
Event: <PyQt4.QtCore.QEvent object at 0x39a1dd0>  | type: 67
```

So I looked up the qt documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#public-types and I can't find event type 67. (I also can't find 64, 65, 66, and a whole host of other event codes. For example, events #12, 13, and 14 exist, but events #15 and 16 don't.)  I've tried google and SE searches, but I can't find reference to Qt event 67 anywhere at all.

So, my question is twofold: **How can I find out what QEvent type 67 is, and why are there gaps in the QEvent codes?**

Sidenote: Why is the table in those docs **NOT** ordered by event number? Seems like that would be the logical way to document the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Qt sources I found the event:

```
ChildInsertedRequest = 67, // send ChildInserted compatibility events to receiver
```

This event comes from Qt3, and defined in Qt3 support library.

Comment: So then all the "missing" event codes are for Qt3 compatibility?

Comment: @zaxvo, I think so. There are not documented.